# Wrong background image path in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to display a background image for a label based on the selected index value of a ddl in mvc 3.
If the selected text is "A" set background image as none, else, set background image with an image . BUt first part(making none) is working for me, again if i select some other value its not resetting the image .its always showing the background null.Its alwys taking the wrong path for the image.

My code is as follows

```
$('#ddl').change(function () {
    if ($("#ddl option:selected").text() == 'Emergency Contact') {
        $('.width label#contact').css("background", "none");
    } else {
        $(".width label#contact").css('background-image', 'url("/Content/images/help.jpg")');
    }
});
```

The else part is always taking wrong image path.My image is in the following folder
    D:\projectname\UI\Content\Images

Comment: Can you add some HTML source code or a link to an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Try `url("Content/images/help.jpg")` .

Comment: _“My image is in the following folder D:\projectname\UI\Content\Images”_ – so `D:\projectname\UI\` is the _web root_ of your project, it is the root of the domain setup you are testing this with?

Answer (score 0):

Your js code seems ok: maybe the path $(".width label#contact") is wrong in the html ? Can you show your html code.

Here is an example where i make it work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="width"><label for="" id="contact" style="width:400px;height:400px;display:block;">helloworld</label></div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <select name="" id="ddl">
        <option value="">other 1</option>
        <option value="">Emergency Contact</option>
        <option value="">other 2</option>

    </select>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#ddl').change(function () {
            if ($("#ddl option:selected").text() == 'Emergency Contact') {
                $('.width label#contact').css("background", "none");
            }
            else {
                $(".width label#contact").css('background-image', 'url("https://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo11w.png")');
                 }
        });
    })

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a realtive path issue. Try this approach:

```
$(".width label#contact").css('background-image', 'url("Content/images/help.jpg")');
```

Also consider using this alternative approach:

CSS:

```
#contact.help {
  background-image:url("Content/images/help.jpg");
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".width label#contact").toggleClass('help');
```